# iOS: table view's title bar covered by navigation bar unexpectedly

Tags: ios

I'm developing a simple UI for an iOS app.
what I've done is I developed it into a table view which has a navigation controller associated to it and had it laid out in Storyboard.

Everything seems working fine, except the navigation bar accidentally cover the view's title bar "Click to select item" as shown in the pictures below.

1. the first picture is when it first shows on the screen.
2. the second one illustrates when I drag the title bar off the covering navigation bar.

what do i do to get completely rid of this?

[image: sadly, my title bar is beneath the navigation bar]

[image: when I move the title down a bit]

[image]

Comment: in viewdidload try self.navigationController.hidden = YES;

Answer (score 1):

In Interface Builder, select your view controller and on the attributes inspector turn off Layout: Wants Full Screen. Then, your layout will automatically adjust its size to make room for the navigation bar.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your viewDidLoad method

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = false
```

It works for me, since you've the same problem with me, I think it's work for you as well.

Answer (score -1):

where u want hide navigation bar use this line

```
self.navigationController.hidden = YES;
```